# Expected value and limit of $P(N_t = k) = \frac{(\gamma t)^k}{k!} e^{-\gamma t}$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I have the following problem where I need to calculate two things, the expected value and a limit. The problem is:

The life expectancy of a product from a factory is defined by the following distribution: $$P(T>t)=e^{-\gamma t}, \ t \geq 0 $$ where $\gamma$ is positive. The random number of bad products in the interval $[0,t]$ has the probability function: $$P(N_t = k) = \frac{(\gamma t)^k}{k!} e^{-\gamma t}, \ k=1,2,\dots$$
Calculate $E[\frac{N_t}{t}]$ and $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} P(|\frac{N_t}{t} - \gamma|\geq \epsilon )$.

$$$$
For calculating the expected value I have problems defining the sum and I do see some similarity between $P(N_t = k)$ and the Poisson distribution by taking $\lambda = \gamma t $ , do I need to divide the function by $t$ before any kind of calculation? And for the limit, I see that it has to do something with the Law of Large Numbers and it might involve $E[\frac{N_t}{t}]$ since that always involves subtracting the $\mu$. Any help with any of the problems is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The distribution for $N_t$ does not sum to $1$. Are you sure the factor is not supposed to be $e^{-\gamma t}$?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Though if the factor is $e^{-\gamma t}$ then it sums to $1-e^{-\gamma t}$ and so perhaps $P(N_t =0)=e^{-\gamma t}$ and you do have a Poisson distribution

Comment: @NinadMunshi I think you're right, I'll edit that part

Comment: Since $t$ is not random $E[N_t/t]=\frac{E[N_t]}{t}$, so you can ignore that bit. Then you're just left to get the expectation of a Poisson distribution which is pretty straightforward. As for the limit, it is *basically* a law of large numbers but since it's not immediately in a convenient form to invoke LLN specifically, it is easier to just work from scratch. Hint: compute the variance of $N_t/t$.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the following

The expected value of a Poisson random variable is $\gamma t$ (adapted for your exercise), then

$$E\left[\frac{N_t}{t}\right]=\frac{\gamma t}{t}=\gamma.$$

Then for LLN the

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty} P(|\frac{N_t}{t} - \gamma|\geq \epsilon )=0.$$

Any doubts or anything not clear?